# Internet access via server

Tags: configuration, internet

We have proxy-server and I run Linux Mint 15 Mate. I've set up network connection and Firefox prompts for login/pass and then connects to Internet. When trying to look for updates/new software, system does not prompt for login/pass and cannot connect to Internet. What should be done to have system accessing Internet and getting updates/installing new software?

Answer (score 2):

```
# man apt.conf
...
....
   http
       http::Proxy sets the default proxy to use for HTTP URIs
....
```

You need to edit config file: /etc/apt/apt.conf to configure APT package handling utility.

Additionally read about [ProxyChains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net) - redirect connections through proxy servers.

Comment: ProxyChains is not exactly what I need. As for editing apt.conf, it did not help. Still cannot connect to repositories to update system or anything like this. It is interesting that Firefox has access through login/pass prompt, whereas Chromium doesn't. I tried to set up it using command `chromium-browser --proxy-server=server:port`, but it still does not connect.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:
`Package Manager -> Settings -> Network`
Re-Enter your Proxy IP/Port and klick on `Authentication` to set login/pass

How to find `Package Manager` this could help: [Mint: How to Open the Package Manager](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1266)

Comment: Clicking on Authentication opens menu login/pass, but these windows remain inactive and I cannot fill them out. What's wrong?